# Show that $d(x,A) = d(x,\bar A)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $d(x,A) = \inf\{d(x,y) | y\in A\}$

Tags: general-topology

I try to solve this problem by the following two methods, but get stuck on both. Any wise advice ? Thanks :-)

- Since $A\subseteq \bar A$,then $d(x,A)\ge d(x,\bar A)$. And I need to show the inverse inequality.
- $\exists\; x_{0}\in \bar A$, such that $d(x,A) = d(x,x_{0})$. But how can I prove that $d(x,\bar A) = d(x,x_{0})$ ?

Comment: Actually, $A \subset B$ implies $d(x,A) \geq d(x,B)$.

Comment: Is $d(x,A)$ defined as infimum of $d(x,a),a \in A$ ? If so should be straightforward.

Comment: @lisyarus Thanks for correction

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, I'll add this definition to the question.

Comment: A point $x_0$ as under the second idea need not exist. So that route is out.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I restrict it to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need completeness. You know already $d(x,A)\ge d(x,\bar A)$.

Assume $d(x, \bar A) < d(x,A)$. Now, choose $C >0$ such that
$$d(x, \bar A) < C < d(x,A) \Rightarrow \exists\,\bar x \in \bar A: \, d(x, \bar A) \leq d(x,\bar x) < C$$

Now, choose a sequence $x_n \in A$ such that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n = \bar x \Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}d(x,x_n) = d(x,\bar x)$$

Note that $d(x,x_n)\geq d(x,A)$. So, it follows

$$C < d(x,A)\leq d(x,\bar x) < C$$
Contradiction! $\Rightarrow d(x, \bar A) = d(x,A)$